# What is considered to be a numerical demonstration of the small world property?

Tags: graph-theory

I want to demonstrate for a graph ensemble created some given method that it does possess the small world property.

Watts and Strogatz do this by varying the relabeling probability p of the Watts-Strogatz network with fixed size n. They show that for certain p, the network exhibits small average path length L and high clustering coefficients compared to regular and random graphs respectively.

On the other hand, I've read in other places such as wikipedia and scholarpedia that small world networks are defined as networks where L grows at most proportionally to log(n).

Obviously these two methods vary greatly as one of them does not consider clustering. What is the accepted standard method for demonstrating the small world property?

Answer (score 0):

The standard definition of small world is:

There exist a short path between any two nodes, and the nodes are able to find such path using only local information.

The manner of searching the path without the knowledge of the full network is called a decentralized routing algorithm.
For example there is a remarkable survey by Kleinberg, which I recommend.